# How to trigger OnServerClick from dynamically generated table in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have created mail inbox page for my system. In page load, it will dynamically generate html table from table data in inbox table. I want to trigger a serverside function when click on each row. When click on specific row, It will get msgID for that row and pass it to serverside function with OnServerClick keyword to open the mail.

Tried many ways for that. But when page is loading, fixed html codes with OnServerClick generate its javascript code to trigger the function. But my table is dynamically generated from page load, won't create those javascripts.

Please help me on this matter.. Thanks.. and sorry for my bad english

here is my code to generate dynamic table in C#

```
foreach (DataRow DRow in tbl.Rows)
{
    int index = tbl.Rows.IndexOf(DRow);
    string From = tbl.Rows[index].Field<string>(3);
    string Subject = tbl.Rows[index].Field<string>(1);
    string Msg = tbl.Rows[index].Field<string>(2);
    DateTime sentTime = tbl.Rows[index].Field<DateTime>(10);
    var month = sentTime.ToString("MMMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    bool isRead = tbl.Rows[index].Field<bool>(11);
    int MsgId = tbl.Rows[index].Field<int>(0);
    if (index != maxMailsPerPage)
    {
        if (isRead == false)
        {
            PnlInbox.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr class=''><td style='visibility:hidden'>" + MsgId + "</td><td><button runat='server' onserverclick='test1'>Add</button></td><td><input type='checkbox' checked/></td><td><b>" + From + "</b></td><td class='right'><b>" + Subject + "</b></td><td class='right'><b>" + Msg + "</b></td><td class='right'><b>" + month + " " + sentTime.Day + "</b></td></tr>"));
        }
        else
        {
            PnlInbox.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<tr class=''><td style='visibility:hidden'>" + MsgId + "</td><td><input type='checkbox' /></td><td>" + From + "</td><td class='right'>" + Subject + "</td><td class='right'>" + Msg + "</td><td class='right'>" + month + " " + sentTime.Day + "</td></tr>"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set the ID to that button, find that button and then bind the event handler to that button.

Comment: I think you can use a asp.net server control just like reapter to do this things.You can add both controls into template and hide one of them depends on `isRead`  in itemdatabound event,also you can use `ItemCommand ` to handle server event. you can see [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df6hth3s(v=vs.85).aspx)